# Loop through JSON object and store results in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, loops

I have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
data = {'A': {'code': 'Ok',
  'tracepoints': [None,
   None,
   {'alternatives_count': 0,
    'location': [-122.419189, 37.753805],
    'distance': 28.078003,
    'hint': '5Qg7hUqpFQA2AAAAOgAAAAwAAAAPAAAAiVMWQq2VIEIAuABB7FgoQTYAAAA6AAAADAAAAA8AAAD4RAAACwi0-M0TQALvB7T4yRRAAgEAXwX5Wu6N',
    'name': '23rd Street',
    'matchings_index': 0,
    'waypoint_index': 0},
   {'alternatives_count': 0,
    'location': [-122.417866, 37.75389],
    'distance': 26.825184,
    'hint': 'K8w6BRinFYAdAAAACwAAAA0AAAAAAAAAIxmmQTSs6kCiuRFBAAAAAB0AAAALAAAADQAAAAAAAAD4RAAANg20-CIUQAJNDbT4MRNAAgIAnxD5Wu6N',
    'name': '23rd Street',
    'matchings_index': 0,
    'waypoint_index': 1},
   {'alternatives_count': 0,
    'location': [-122.416896, 37.75395],
    'distance': 16.583412,
    'hint': 'Jcw6BSzMOoUqAAAAQwAAABAAAAANAAAA0i_uQb3SOEKKPC9BG1EaQSoAAABDAAAAEAAAAA0AAAD4RAAAABG0-F4UQALyELT48xRAAgEAnxD5Wu6N',
    'name': '23rd Street',
    'matchings_index': 0,
    'waypoint_index': 2},
   {'alternatives_count': 7,
    'location': [-122.415502, 37.754028],
    'distance': 10.013916,
    'hint': 'Jsw6hbN6kQBmAAAACAAAABAAAAANAAAAQOKOQg89nkCKPC9BEMcOQWYAAAAIAAAAEAAAAA0AAAD4RAAAcha0-KwUQAJ6FrT4UhRAAgEAbwX5Wu6N',
    'name': '23rd Street',
    'matchings_index': 0,
    'waypoint_index': 3}],
  'matchings': [{'duration': 50.6,
    'distance': 325.2,
    'weight': 50.6,
    'geometry': 'y{h_gAh~znhF}@k[OmFMoFcAea@IeD[uMAYKsDMsDAe@}@u_@g@aTMwFMwFwAqq@',
    'confidence': 0.374625,
    'weight_name': 'routability',
    'legs': [{'steps': [],
      'weight': 18.8,
      'distance': 116.7,
      'annotation': {'nodes': [1974590926,
        4763953263,
        65359046,
        4763953265,
        5443374298,
        2007343352]},
      'summary': '',
      'duration': 18.8},
     {'steps': [],
      'weight': 12.2,
      'distance': 85.6,
      'annotation': {'nodes': [5443374298,
        2007343352,
        4763953266,
        65359043,
        4763953269,
        2007343354,
        4763953270]},
      'summary': '',
      'duration': 12.2},
     {'steps': [],
      'weight': 19.6,
      'distance': 122.9,
      'annotation': {'nodes': [2007343354,
        4763953270,
        65334199,
        4763953274,
        2007343347]},
      'summary': '',
      'duration': 19.6}]}]},
 'B': {'code': 'Ok',
  'tracepoints': [{'alternatives_count': 0,
    'location': [-122.387971, 37.727587],
    'distance': 11.53267,
    'hint': 'xHWRAEJ2kYALAAAArQAAAA4AAAAsAAAAnpH1QDVG8EJWgBdBa2v0QQsAAACtAAAADgAAACwAAAD4RAAA_YG0-GOtPwJKgrT4t60_AgIA3wf5Wu6N',
    'name': 'Underwood Avenue',
    'matchings_index': 0,
    'waypoint_index': 0},
   {'alternatives_count': 0,
    'location': [-122.388563, 37.727175],
    'distance': 13.565054,
    'hint': 'w3WRgBuxOgVPAAAACAAAABMAAAASAAAA7ONaQo4CrUDv7U1BJdFAQU8AAAAIAAAAEwAAABIAAAD4RAAArX-0-MerPwIsgLT4gqs_AgIAbw35Wu6N',
    'name': 'Jennings Street',
    'matchings_index': 0,
    'waypoint_index': 1},
   {'alternatives_count': 1,
    'location': [-122.388478, 37.725984],
    'distance': 9.601917,
    'hint': 't3WRABexOoWcAAAAbAAAABEAAAALAAAAdujYQqu4lUJXHD1B9-ruQJwAAABsAAAAEQAAAAsAAAD4RAAAAoC0-CCnPwJCgLT4Zqc_AgIAHxP5Wu6N',
    'name': 'Wallace Avenue',
    'matchings_index': 0,
    'waypoint_index': 2}],
  'matchings': [{'duration': 50,
    'distance': 270.4,
    'weight': 50,
    'geometry': 'euu}fAd_~lhFoAlCMTuAvCvC|Bh@`@hXbUnAdADBhDzCzClCXVzZnW\\X~CnC~@qBLWnWej@',
    'confidence': 1e-06,
    'weight_name': 'routability',
    'legs': [{'steps': [],
      'weight': 17.8,
      'distance': 84.8,
      'annotation': {'nodes': [5443147626,
        6360865540,
        6360865536,
        65307580,
        6360865535,
        6360865539,
        6360865531]},
      'summary': '',
      'duration': 17.8},
     {'steps': [],
      'weight': 32.2,
      'distance': 185.6,
      'annotation': {'nodes': [6360865539,
        6360865531,
        6360865525,
        65343521,
        6360865527,
        6360865529,
        6360865523,
        6360865520,
        65321110,
        6360865519,
        6360865522,
        6376329343]},
      'summary': '',
      'duration': 32.2}]}]},
 'C': {'code': 'Ok',
  'tracepoints': [None,
   None,
   {'alternatives_count': 0,
    'location': [-122.443682, 37.713254],
    'distance': 6.968076,
    'hint': 'QXo6hUR6OgUAAAAANQAAAAAAAAAkAAAAAAAAAOCMMUEAAAAA_Z1yQQAAAAAbAAAAAAAAACQAAAD4RAAAXqiz-GZ1PwKiqLP4hnU_AgAAzxL5Wu6N',
    'name': '',
    'matchings_index': 0,
    'waypoint_index': 0},
   {'alternatives_count': 0,
    'location': [-122.442428, 37.714335],
    'distance': 16.488956,
    'hint': 'E3o6BVRukYAJAAAAIgAAAGgAAAAUAAAA2RnSQL_5uUEPjI9CBTlaQQkAAAAiAAAAaAAAABQAAAD4RAAARK2z-J95PwKTrLP4b3k_AgEAXxX5Wu6N',
    'name': 'Allison Street',
    'matchings_index': 0,
    'waypoint_index': 1},
   {'alternatives_count': 1,
    'location': [-122.441751, 37.712761],
    'distance': 17.311636,
    'hint': 'Fno6hRl6OgWZAAAANwAAAAAAAAAKAAAAH4vUQgKXFkIAAAAAXtbYQJkAAAA3AAAAAAAAAAoAAAD4RAAA6a-z-HlzPwKjsLP4q3M_AgAAHwr5Wu6N',
    'name': 'Allison Street',
    'matchings_index': 0,
    'waypoint_index': 2}],
  'matchings': [{'duration': 64.1,
    'distance': 420.1,
    'weight': 66.7,
    'geometry': 'kuy|fAbyjphFcBxEmE`FqJkKiBqBuP}Qgc@ie@eAiAcB}ArA_Eb@mAjKkDnBo@fe@mOrw@kW',
    'confidence': 7.3e-05,
    'weight_name': 'routability',
    'legs': [{'steps': [],
      'weight': 40.1,
      'distance': 235.2,
      'annotation': {'nodes': [5440513673,
        5440513674,
        5440513675,
        65363070,
        1229920760,
        65307726,
        6906452420,
        1229920717,
        65361047,
        1229920749,
        554163599,
        3978809925]},
      'summary': '',
      'duration': 37.5},
     {'steps': [],
      'weight': 26.6,
      'distance': 184.9,
      'annotation': {'nodes': [554163599, 3978809925, 65345518, 8256268328]},
      'summary': '',
      'duration': 26.6}]}]}}
```

I would like to extract the values under the key nodes per user (A, B and C) and store these values in a pandas dataframe, together with the corresponding user. Like below:

```
    value        user
    1974590926  A
    4763953263  A
    65359046    A
    4763953265  A
    5443374298  A
    2007343352  A
    5443374298  A
    2007343352  A
    4763953266  A
    65359043    A
    4763953269  A
    2007343354  A
    4763953270  A
    2007343354  A
    4763953270  A
    65334199    A
    4763953274  A
    2007343347  A
    5443147626  B
    6360865540  B
    6360865536  B
    65307580    B
    6360865535  B
    6360865539  B
    6360865531  B
    6360865539  B
    6360865531  B
    6360865525  B
    65343521    B
    6360865527  B
    6360865529  B
    6360865523  B
    6360865520  B
    65321110    B
    6360865519  B
    6360865522  B
    6376329343  B
    5440513673  C
    5440513674  C
    5440513675  C
    65363070    C
    1229920760  C
    65307726    C
    6906452420  C
    1229920717  C
    65361047    C
    1229920749  C
    554163599   C
    3978809925  C
    554163599   C
    3978809925  C
    65345518    C
    8256268328  C
```

I am able to extract and store only the nodes belonging to user C to a pandas dataframe with the code below. However, I struggle to add the user column and the other nodes with their corresponding user. Any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd
nodes_df = pd.DataFrame({'node':{}})

for user in output[user]['matchings'][0]['legs']:
    result  = user['annotation']['nodes']
    values_temp = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['value'])
    values_df = values_df.append(values_temp, ignore_index=True)
values_df.node = values_df.value.astype(int)
values_df

    value
0   5440513673
1   5440513674
2   5440513675
3   65363070
4   1229920760
5   65307726
6   6906452420
7   1229920717
8   65361047
9   1229920749
10  554163599
11  3978809925
12  554163599
13  3978809925
14  65345518
15  8256268328
```

Comment: What is the output of your current code?

Comment: I've updated my question with the output of my current code

Comment: `output` is your json object? and you have set `user = c`?

Comment: `output` is indeed my json object. The values `A` `B` and `C` in the Json object are the `user` keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`json_normalize()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) with `record_path` and then [**`concat()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the users:

```py
dfs = []
for user in output.keys():
    df = pd.json_normalize(output, record_path=[user, 'matchings', 'legs', 'annotation', 'nodes'])
    df['user'] = user
    dfs.append(df)
nodes_df = pd.concat(dfs).rename(columns={0: 'node'})

#        node  user
#  1974590926     A
#  4763953263     A
#    65359046     A
#         ...   ...
#  3978809925     C
#    65345518     C
#  8256268328     C
```

---

If there are some users with missing `matchings`, you can check `if 'matchings' in output[user]`:

```py
dfs = []
for user in output.keys():
    if 'matchings' in output[user]:
        df = pd.json_normalize(output, record_path=[user, 'matchings', 'legs', 'annotation', 'nodes'])
        df['user'] = user
        dfs.append(df)
nodes_df = pd.concat(dfs).rename(columns={0: 'node'})
```

---

If the `output` keys are like `('2018-02-03', 'A')` and you're iterating them as `trip`, you need to access its `date` and `user` as `trip[0]` and `trip[1]`:

```py
dfs = []
for trip in output.keys():
    if 'matchings' in output[trip]:
        df = pd.json_normalize(output, record_path=[trip, 'matchings', 'legs', 'annotation', 'nodes'])
        df['date'] = trip[0]
        df['user'] = trip[1]
        dfs.append(df)
nodes_df = pd.concat(dfs).rename(columns={0: 'node'})
```

Comment: I noticed that when a `user`, let's say C, does not have a `'matchings'`, for example: `'C':{"message":"Could not find a matching segment for any coordinate.", "code":"NoSegment"}`, the code above will throw a `KeyError: 'matchings'`. How to prevent this?

Comment: @sampeterson It seems pandas isn't able to handle this directly. I updated the answer with a workaround that tests `if 'matchings' in output[user]`.

Comment: Last question: If my JSON object would also have a `date` key, besides a `user` key like so: `{('2018-02-03', 'A'): {'code': 'Ok', 'tracepoints': [None ...`, how do I add the date to an extra column `date`? I was hoping I could run `dfs = []
for trip in output.keys():
    if 'matchings' in output[trip]:
        df = pd.json_normalize(output, record_path=[date, user, 'matchings', 'legs', 'annotation', 'nodes'])
        df['date'] = date
        df['user'] = user
        dfs.append(df)
nodes_df = pd.concat(dfs).rename(columns={0: 'node'})`, but it gives me an error.

Answer (score 1):

We want to put all the node values in [legs]

If you want the simplest way with just for loop:

```
nodes = []
user = []

for i in output.keys():
    for j in output[i]['matchings'][0]['legs']:
        for k in j['annotation']['nodes']:
            col1.append(k)
            col2.append(i)

d = {'nodes':nodes, 'user':user}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [jmespath](https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/) module to extract the data, before recombining within the dataframe; you should get some speed up, since the iteration is within the dictionary:

The summary for [jmespath](https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/) is : if accessing a key, then use dot, if the data is within a list, then use the `[]` to access the data:

```
#pip install jmespath
import jmespath
from itertools import chain

query ={letter: jmespath.compile(f"{letter}.matchings[].legs[].annotation.nodes")
        for letter in ("A", "B", "C")}

result = {letter: pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(expression.search(output)),
                               columns=['node']) 
          for letter, expression in query.items()}

result = pd.concat(result).droplevel(-1).rename_axis(index='user').reset_index()

result.head(15)
 
   user        node
0     A  1974590926
1     A  4763953263
2     A    65359046
3     A  4763953265
4     A  5443374298
5     A  2007343352
6     A  5443374298
7     A  2007343352
8     A  4763953266
9     A    65359043
10    A  4763953269
11    A  2007343354
12    A  4763953270
13    A  2007343354
14    A  4763953270
```